# Why isn't my json product list loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

**I'd really like to understand why isn't my list loading.
Here is my json and jquery, and my HTML.
The console shows 0 errors, and the list just appears blank. I'd really appreciate some help, I'm new to this json thing. Many thanks in advance!**

```js
// Json array
    var productList = {"products": [
        {"description": "Bata Bordada", "color": "amarelo", "size":"P", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Chapéu de Praia com Fivela", "color": "cinza", "size":"M", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Vestido Texturizado", "color": "branco", "size":"G", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Bata Bordada", "color": "branco", "size":"GG", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Chapéu de Praia com Fivela", "color": "amarelo", "size":"36", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Vestido Texturizado", "color": "azul", "size":"38", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Bata Bordada", "color": "cinza", "size":"40", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Chapéu de Praia com Fivela", "color": "branco", "size":"42", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Vestido Texturizado", "color": "cinza", "size":"44", "price": "390"}
    ]
    };


function loadList() {

    var list = $("#ProductList").listview();
    list.sort();

   $(productList.products).each(function(index){
    $(list).append(
        '<li class="product-it"> <article class="product"> <span class="prd-img-wrapper"> <img class="prd-img" src="img/vestido1.jpg"></span> <h2 class="prd-tit">' + this.description + '</h2> <span class="prd-wrap"><span class="prd-price"><span class="prd-prc">' +  this.price + '</span></br> <span class="prd-par">até 5x de R$30,00</span></span><a class="prd-cart" href="#">Adicionar ao carrinho.</a></span></article></li>');
   });

   $(list).listview("refresh");

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <title>Teste Vaga Front End</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="loadList()">
<section class="products">
    <header class="products-hdr">
        <h3 class="mobile-btn order">Ordenar</h3>
        <select class="prd-order">
             <option value="MaisRecentes">Mais Recentes</option>
             <option value="MaiorPreco">Maior Preço</option>
             <option value="MenorPreco">Menor Preço</option>
        </select>
    </header>
    <ul id="ProductList" class="product-lt">    
    </ul>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `listview`

Comment: Also I'm kind of desperate cause I have to deliver this code running by monday ^_^

Comment: @user2181397 you got me. I don't know. I just copied the code from somewhere else and just changed the variables to fit my needs :( I didn't even notice this listview thing... :(

Comment: It is not possible to help unless you clarify . also how does this drop down is related with the json table

Comment: As an aside, there is no JSON in your question. What you have as an object (that has a property that is an array of other objects) defined via an object literal (or "object initialiser"). JSON is textual data exchange format that looks like JavaScript's object literal syntax.

Comment: oh god I'm a total noob for json. I have no idea what i've done. hahahah

Comment: is there any simple way to fix this?

Comment: You should really try breaking up problems like this into parts, and try to understand each piece. Stack Overflow is not a free programmers for hire kind of service...if you can identify specific questions it's easier to get help via a search engine (immediate results) and if you're not sure from a quick search, then SO can be a great resource

Comment: Your question is incomplete and not sure of your expectation .But this [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/LnL90gug/) is just to help you to draw the DOM

Comment: As for "fixing" things, you first need to know what's wrong. It's rare for someone to be able to spot problems without looking at a console or log for an error message. That's always the starting place....

Comment: I said in the description the console shows 0 errors, and that is exactly why I came here :( I copied the code from another question and the person said it was working

Comment: thank you @user2181397 I will take a look <3

Comment: to be honest, I'm surprised `.listview()` doesn't result in an error (especially if you're not sure what it is, as this is a sign you probably don't have that plugin included on your page...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working with jQuery Mobile ! So you need to include it in your page: [jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js) and [jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css)

Please check this working demo:

```js
// Json array
    var productList = {"products": [
        {"description": "Bata Bordada", "color": "amarelo", "size":"P", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Chapéu de Praia com Fivela", "color": "cinza", "size":"M", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Vestido Texturizado", "color": "branco", "size":"G", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Bata Bordada", "color": "branco", "size":"GG", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Chapéu de Praia com Fivela", "color": "amarelo", "size":"36", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Vestido Texturizado", "color": "azul", "size":"38", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Bata Bordada", "color": "cinza", "size":"40", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Chapéu de Praia com Fivela", "color": "branco", "size":"42", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Vestido Texturizado", "color": "cinza", "size":"44", "price": "390"}
    ]
    };


function loadList() {

    var list = $("#ProductList").listview();
    list.sort();

   $(productList.products).each(function(index){
    $(list).append(
        '<li class="product-it"> <article class="product"> <span class="prd-img-wrapper"> <img class="prd-img" src="img/vestido1.jpg"></span> <h2 class="prd-tit">' + this.description + '</h2> <span class="prd-wrap"><span class="prd-price"><span class="prd-prc">' +  this.price + '</span></br> <span class="prd-par">até 5x de R$30,00</span></span><a class="prd-cart" href="#">Adicionar ao carrinho.</a></span></article></li>');
   });

   $(list).listview("refresh");

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <title>Teste Vaga Front End</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="js/js.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="loadList()">
<section class="products">
    <header class="products-hdr">
        <h3 class="mobile-btn order">Ordenar</h3>
        <select class="prd-order">
             <option value="MaisRecentes">Mais Recentes</option>
             <option value="MaiorPreco">Maior Preço</option>
             <option value="MenorPreco">Menor Preço</option>
        </select>
    </header>
    <ul id="ProductList" class="product-lt">    
    </ul>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: More accurate to say, the code they copied appears to use jQuery mobile...but seems to be the most probable issue at this point with the given information

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the `.listView()` references. That <s>seems to be some sort of plugin</s> is likely from jQuery mobile which you have not included on your page. So add in an include for your preferred version of jquery-mobile.js, or remove references to `.listView()` as follows:

```
var list = $("#ProductList");
```

In context:

```js
var productList = {"products": [
        {"description": "Bata Bordada", "color": "amarelo", "size":"P", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Chapéu de Praia com Fivela", "color": "cinza", "size":"M", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Vestido Texturizado", "color": "branco", "size":"G", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Bata Bordada", "color": "branco", "size":"GG", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Chapéu de Praia com Fivela", "color": "amarelo", "size":"36", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Vestido Texturizado", "color": "azul", "size":"38", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Bata Bordada", "color": "cinza", "size":"40", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Chapéu de Praia com Fivela", "color": "branco", "size":"42", "price": "390"},
        {"description": "Vestido Texturizado", "color": "cinza", "size":"44", "price": "390"}
    ]};

function loadList() {

    var list = $("#ProductList");
    // list.sort(); commented because this won't do anything useful

   $(productList.products).each(function(index){
    $(list).append(
        '<li class="product-it"> <article class="product"> <span class="prd-img-wrapper"> <img class="prd-img" src="img/vestido1.jpg"></span> <h2 class="prd-tit">' + this.description + '</h2> <span class="prd-wrap"><span class="prd-price"><span class="prd-prc">' +  this.price + '</span></br> <span class="prd-par">até 5x de R$30,00</span></span><a class="prd-cart" href="#">Adicionar ao carrinho.</a></span></article></li>');
   });
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="loadList()">
<section class="products">
    <!-- header element with select omitted for brevity -->
    <ul id="ProductList" class="product-lt">    
    </ul>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: It's jquery mobile please check my answer.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH - Oh right, cool, thanks. I've made an update, but assuming the OP is trying to use jQuery mobile [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38157178/615754) is the way to go.

Comment: please take a look at my snippet is a working demo !

Comment: actually this jquery mobile is going to help me a lot. Thank you very much for this

Comment: @BeatrizRachel - If you want jQuery mobile then you should accept [Ismail's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38157178/615754) instead of mine, because Ismail spotted that and I only edited it into my response for completeness (but I didn't put it in my demo because I didn't come up with it). If you *don't* want jQuery mobile then my answer shows you what to do.

Comment: I think i'm actually going to use both, cause I need both versions. And I'm hoping I'm gonna find some useful features for the mobile version in the jquery mobile thing. thank you very much.